# Using data.table::fread on column containing a single double quote

Tags: r, io, data.table

I've been googling and reading posts on problems similar but different to the one described below; apologies if this is a duplicate.

I've got a csv file with a field which can contain, among other things, a single instance of a double quote (object descriptions sometimes containing lengths specified in inches).

When I call `fread` as follows

```
data_in <- data.table::fread(file_path,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

the resulting data frame contains two consecutive double quotes in instances where the source file only had one (e.g., the string which appears in the raw csv as

> MI|WIRE 9" BGD

appears in the data frame as

> MI|WIRE 9"" BGD

).

This character field can also contain commas, semicolons, single quotes in any quantity, and many other characters which I cannot identify.

This is a problem as I need the exact string to match another dataset's values with `merge` (in fact, the file being read in was originally written from `r` with `fwrite`).

I assume that nearly any io problem I'm wrestling with can be solved with `readLines` and some elbow grease, but I quite like `fread`. Based on what I've read online this seems similar to problems that others have faced and so I'm guessing that some tweaking of `fread`'s parameters will solve this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Why wouldn't  a gsub solve your problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure which gsub rules would be adequate: replacing two double quotes with a single instance could be problematic as the file may validly contain strings with such values, and I'm not sure what other modifications to the raw values `fread` is performing. If I'm going down the processing route I may just use `readLines` directly - I'm looking for a solution that reads the file in with at least the accuracy of Excel, which does faithfully represent all values without the need to subsequently process ...